# What would be the Linq code for this grouping using VB.NET 2008?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2008, ienumerable

I have a population aged from 0 to 119 years.

I wish to group this population from the age of 15 to 49 according to the following hypothesis:

1. 15 to 19;
2. 20 to 24;
3. 25 to 29;
4. 30 to 34;
5. 35 to 39;
6. 40 to 44;
7. 45 to 49.

Any age apart these are useless for the calculation I need to perform. Here are some sample data and code.

I have an AnnualPopulation class which represents the demographic population for each year of age.

```
Public Class AnnualPopulation
    Public Id as Integer
    Public Year As Integer
    Public Gender As String
    Public YearsOfAge As Double?() = New Double?(119) { }
End Class
```

Then, the YearsOfAge array/collection property contains the number of people based on their gender. For instance:

```
AnnualPopulation.Year = 2009
AnnualPopulation.Gender = "F"c
For age As Integer = 0 To AnnualPopulation.YearsOfAge.Length - 1 Step 1
    YearsOfAge(age) = 42356.67F 'Of course, this number varies from a years of age to another!'
Next
```

I would then like to group such as follows:

```
Dim groups() As Double = New Double(6) { }
For age As Integer = 15 To 49 Step 1
    Dim index As Integer = 0

    Select Case age
        Case 15 to 19
            index = 0
        Case 20 To 24
            index = 1
        Case 25 To 29
            index = 2
        Case 30 To 34
            index = 3
        Case 35 To 39
            index = 4
        Case 40 To 44
            index = 5
        Case 45 To 49
            index = 6
    End Select

    groups(index) += AnnualPopulation.YearsOfAge(age - 1)
Next
```

> *This way, I would have the sum of population for each range of year of age*

So, I though of grouping them, and then I have no common key to group them by, no luck! =P In C#, I guess this would do what I need:

```
double[] groups = new double[7];
Enumerable.Range(15, 34).ToList().ForEach(age => {
    groups[(int)(age % 4)] += annualPopulation.YearsOfAge[age - 1].HasValue 
                              ? annualPopulation.YearsOfAge[age - 1].Value : 0.0;
});
```

Which I don't seem to be able to achieve in VB.NET 2008 except if I try to go along with `New Action(Of T1, T2)` or else `Func(Of Double?, TKey)`. I'm not comfortable at all with these! =( (*Underlying question: Why is it so complicated in VB.NET to work with lambdas!?*)

My code actually works, I'm only looking for a nicer and perhaps more readable solution, though this is easy to understand what I'm trying to achieve here.

Anyway, anyone has a clue about how to go with this?

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your `switch` statement in the group by selector; the keys will be 0 to 6 respectively then. After that, you simply can use the `Sum` operator on each group.

In C#, it would look like this (you don't have ranged `case`s in C#):

```
var filtered = data
    .Where(item => item.Age > 15 && item.Age <= 49)
    .GroupBy(item => 
                    {
                     if(item.Age > 15 && item.Age <= 19)
                       return 0;
                     else if(item.Age <= 24)
                       return 1;
                     else if(item.Age <= 29)
                       return 2;
                     else if(item.Age <= 34)
                       return 3;
                     else if(item.Age <= 39)
                       return 4;
                     else if(item.Age <= 44)
                       return 5;
                     else if(item.Age <= 49)
                       return 6;
                    });
```

After that, you can create a dictionary:

```
var dict = filtered.ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => /* do something with the sequence */);
```

Comment: +1 This is a very clever and nice answer you got there! =) Thanks! Aside, my question is how to do it in VB.NET? That is my pain actually, though I shall try to translate this even if it requires a delegate sub using a `New Action` or a `New Func`.

Comment: yes, you'd have to adjust for missing language features in vb; it should still be doable, but not so pretty. I can't help you with that though, as I don't do vb, but you should have an idea now what path to follow.

Comment: Thanks! I shall try your solution and see if it suits my need which I doubt it wouldn't. Thanks for your assistance! =)

Comment: I guess this won't work for me as my AnnualPopulation.YearsOfAge over which I have to filter the data only contains `Double?`s, so there is no age to filter here. In fact, the age is given only by the index within the list, so age 15 would be `AnnualPopulation.YearsOfAge(14).Value`. So, if I want to get this, I need to include the AnnualPopulation object instance and get the IndexOf a Double value, which can't be assured to be unique.